# JS Как можно получить доступ к аргументам функции, которая сама передана в качестве аргумента?

Tags: javascript

Вот такой код хочу у себя использовать. Раньше название зависимостей передавал в массиве через дополнительный аргумент, вот решил попробовать без него, но не уверен что технически есть такая возможность.

```
app.onPage('anyPage', function (depends1, depends2, depends3) {
    //
});

Application.prototype.onPage = function () {

    var page = arguments[0],
        callable = arguments[1],
        callableArguments = [], // здесь хочу получить доступ к массиву агрументов callable
        depends = [];

    depends = callableArguments.map(this.getModuleByName);

    callable.call(this.getDocument(), dependsNames);
};
```

Как можно получить доступ к аргументам функции, которая сама передана в качестве аргумента?

p.s. подобную реализацию видел в angularJS

Comment: массив аргументов доступен/существует внутри функции - когда она вызвана - а не снаружи

Comment: Судя по вашему коду, `Application.prototype.onPage` дожен **передавать** аргументы функции `callable`. Поэтому получение в этом методе аргументов `callable` **не имеет смысла**. Он итак их знает. Есть у меня такое чувство, что вы не до конца понимаете, как работают анонимные функции в JavaScript

Comment: @DmitriySimushev Я прекрасно понимаю как это работает. Это попытка внедрения зависимости таким способом, без дополнительно определения массива с равносильным количеством аргументов!

`app.onPage('anyPage', ['d1', 'd2', 'd3'], function (d1, d2, d3) {});`

Таким образом у меня есть доступ через arguments[1], я могу создать мне нужные объекты и передать массивом в callable функцию. Но дело в том что хоту узнать, можно ли сделать это без массива!

Comment: @JILeXanDR - подумайте чем отличаются формальные параметеры в определении функции и их значения, передаваемые в функцию вызывающим кодом.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

В AngularJS это используется для "неявного" внедрения зависимостей (Dependency Injection). Суть реализации в том, что если JavaScript функцию привести к строке, то на выходе получится весь текст функции в качестве строки, включая ее объявление:

```
function fn (foo, bar) {
    console.log(foo); return bar;
}

var fnStr = fn.toString();
```

Переменная `fnStr` будет содержать строку:

```
"function fn(foo, bar) { console.log(foo); return bar; }"
```

Далее это строка парсится регулярными выражениями и из нее извлекаются названия аргументов функции: `foo` и `bar`. Зная эти названия и имея список зарегистрированных модулей, можно выполнять их загрузку.

[Здесь](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/44a96a4c140873d9fd8484d870af83a0bb9acabd/src/auto/injector.js#L57) можно взглянуть на то, как это реализовано в AngularJS (функция `annotate`).

В целом в сообществе AngularJS не рекоммендуется использовать неявное определение зависимостей, т.к. если код планируется проводить через uglify, то все названия переменных и в том числе названия аргументов функций сокращаются до одного символа, после чего функция примет приблизительно такой вид:

```
function a (b, c) {
    console.log(b); return c;
}
```

В этом случае, приведение функции к строке никак не поможет понять, какие же зависимости были изначально определены.

Comment: спасибо! то что и хотел узнать