# Angular styleguide. Явное внедрение зависимостей

Tags: javascript, angularjs

В стайл-гайде по Ангуляру от Тода Мотто в некоторых примерах используется явное DI. Так же я замечал этот прием в примерах других опытных разработчиков.

```
angular
   .module('app.core')
   .factory('dataservice', dataservice);

dataservice.$inject = ['$http', 'logger'];

function dataservice($http, logger) {
   return {
       getAvengers: getAvengers
   };

   ...
}
```

В чем смысл этого дополнительного кода,

```
dataservice.$inject = ['$http', 'logger'];
```

если зависимости подтягиваются автоматически?

Comment: в том что после минификации неизменны только строки.

Comment: @shatal, очень скромно) Не могли бы дать развернутый ответ? То есть смысл в том, чтобы избежать проблем при минификации? Сейчас их кстати нет, хотя этот прием я не использую.

Comment: Может быть вам поможет мой ответ на схожий вопрос: [здесь](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/447020/js-%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B4%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%83%D0%BF-%D0%BA-%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B3%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BC-%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%B2-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81/447030#447030)

Comment: @MichaelRadionov , понял, спасибо. Но это странно. Какой смысл пытаться сохранить эту малую часть кода читабельной при минификации, если весь остальной код таковым не будет :)

Comment: @Harvey, правильнее будет сказать - читабельным для Angular. Как заметил @shatal, строки не меняются при минификации, следовательно благодаря этому коду `dataservice.$inject = ['$http', 'logger'];` Angular поймет, какие зависимости нужно подставить в сервис, в то время как аргументы конструктора сервиса после минификации уже будут выглядеть по-другому (т.к. это не строки).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

@Harvey, хотя выше вам уже дали верный ответ, позволю себе немного дополнить. Если вы не хотите указывать явные названия зависимостей руками, то вы можете использовать [ng-annotate](https://github.com/olov/ng-annotate) для автоматизации процесса (есть версия для Grung и Gulp). Эта утилита будет явно вставлять аннотации зависимостей за вас:

```
angular.module("MyMod").controller("MyCtrl", function($scope, $timeout) {});
```

преобразуется в

```
angular.module("MyMod").controller("MyCtrl", ["$scope", "$timeout", function($scope, $timeout) {}]);
```

Соотвественно следущим шагом билда этот код можно безбоязненно минифицировать. И, чтобы у вас была полная увереность что минифицированный код работает как надо, рекомендую добавить опциональный флаг **ng-strict-di**.

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-strict-di>
```

В этом режиме Dependency Injector строго проверяет что все компоненты имеют аннотации.

Comment: Спасибо, теперь понял окончательно и бесповоротно